# Create Eclipse Project From Host to Guest Using VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, eclipse

I have windows 7 host and ubuntu 10 guest. I am using a bridged connection and can quite easily access files on the guest from the host. I can create files from within win explorer, edit files, delete files, everything..within explorer (or even notepad++).

Sadly, if I try to create a project from within eclipse I am getting forbidden error on attempt to create the project files on the network drive. Is there any way I can remedy this?

Cringe if you will but can I turn off this security for my vm? I don't need security, this is literally just for my desktop computer - the only reason I am using a vm is as an alternative to wamp.

Answer (score 1):

[You don't state what software you are using for your VM, but you tagged it with "virtualbox," so I will assume that's what you are using.]

Instead of using a mapped network drive for sharing between your Windows host and your Ubuntu VM, why not just use the Shared Folder capability provided by VirtualBox. The folder is just a normal folder on your Windows 7 host.  Under Unbuntu, you can mount the folder anywhere you want with any file permissions you want (once you have the VirtualBox Guest Extensions installed).  The networking layer is never involved.